# Phpmailer Addattachment goes wrong

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, attachment

i'm a php beginner,and my english can be wrong... i tried to find a way to send a mail via phpmailer with an attachment for a form.
At the moment the file is uploaded on a directory on the server, but there's 2 files, one is good, the other is 0 byte, and the code attach that file... the wrong one! and i can't find what's wrong...
Also there's no message show when the mail is sent...
I am very gratefull if someone can help me! 
**HTML**:

```
<form action="formulaire.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table align="center"><tr><td><label for="nom">Votre nom :</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nom" required/><br></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label for="prenom">Votre prénom: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="prenom" required/><br></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label for="societe">Société: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="societe" required/><br></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label for="phone">Téléphone: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone" required/><br></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label for="email">Votre E-mail: </label></td>
    <td><input type="email" name="email" required/><br></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label for="message">Texte explicatif :</label></td><br>
        <td><textarea name="message" rows="2" cols="50" required></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000"> Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td align="center"><input type="submit" value="Envoyer"></td></tr></table>
</form>
```

**PHP**:

```
<?php
            if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {
            $uploadfile = tempnam('upload', $_POST['nom']);
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile.".jpg")) {
            require_once("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
            require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->From = $_POST['email'];
            $mail->IsMail ();
            $mail->ClearAddresses ();
            $mail->AddAddress ("xxx@xxxxx.com");
            $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = 'xxxxx';
            $mail->Body = '<ul>
            <li>Nom : '. $_POST['nom'] .'</li>
            <li>Prenom : '. $_POST['prenom'] .'</li>
            <li>Societe : '. $_POST['societe'] .'</li>
            <li>Telephone : '. $_POST['phone'] .'</li>
            <li>E-mail : '. $_POST['email'] .'</li>
            '.$filename;'
        </ul>';
            $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, '');
            if(!$mail->send()) {
            $msg = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            $msg = "Message sent!";
        }
    } else {
        $msg = 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You're defining `$msg` but never displaying it. Check the value of `$uploadfile` and the return value of the call to `addAttachment()`. Don't use the submitter's address as the From address; it is forgery and will cause the message to fail SPF checks. You don't need to load the PHPMailer class *and* the autoloader; the autoloader is all you need.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, i corrected the msg is now showing the status!

Comment: i remove the phpmailerclass and keep the autoloader. i don't understand the problem with the From adress! i need it in my mail... what can i put instead of that?  i checked the value of the $uploadfile and it was the 0b file. So i change the line $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile.".jpg", ''); and then now the file is attached in the mail! should be good like that...

Comment: Put your own address in the from address, put the submitter's address in a reply-to using `addReplyTo()`.

Answer (score 0):

[`tempnam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) actually creates an empty file when you call it. This is how it "reserves" a unique temporary file for later use. However, when you call `move_uploaded_file()` you are appending ".jpg" to the end. This is why you have two copies of the files, and one them is empty.

Later in your message, you are attaching `$uploadfile` instead of `$uploadfile.'.jpg'`; this is why the 0-length file is the one attached to your e-mail. Note that with the second paramater, you can name the file whatever you want and that will be used instead of the file's name on disk. This would be better in your case because the user won't get a file with a random gibberish name; instead you can use the original name from the `$_FILES['userfile']` array.